# Working example of Rails 3.1 + Juggernaut Instant Messenger?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, juggernaut, instant, messenger

Are there any decent example apps for an ruby on rails 3 instant Messenger app based on any of the publish-subscribe messaging system Juggernaut?

- 1-1 chat with method of adding 2 users to a "conversation"
- Ways to protect the 1-1 conversation to only visible to those 2 persons in it
- basic frontend implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example which might help you:

https://github.com/maccman/holla

Comment: Still haven't found an instant 1-1 messenger example, are there any examples like that available?

Answer (score 1):

If you are not already aware of it you may also be interested in [pusher.com](http://pusher.com/) as a 'hassle free' alternative.
The only drawbacks are that their free version is limited to a maximum of 20 connections and 100,000 messages per day.

Comment: I know pusher thx using faye for now pusher is commercial and I'm just building a fun project for personal use

Answer (score 0):

I will be using Faye since it supports direct push. 
Juggernaut still seems a very nice solution also though